# ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED on third level domain localhost for WPMU

Tags: wordpress, apache, redirect, vhosts

I'm setting up WP Network on my localhost. I'm on windows, using Uniform Server, and I've setup a vhost like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:${AP_PORT}>
 ServerAdmin webmaster@themes.wp
 DocumentRoot ${US_ROOTF}/vhosts/themeswp
 ServerName themes.wp
 ServerAlias www.themes.wp *.themes.wp
 ErrorLog logs/themes.wp-error.log
 CustomLog logs/themes.wp-access.log common
 <Directory "${HOME}\vhosts\themeswp">
   Options Indexes Includes 
   AllowOverride All   
   Require all granted 
 </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

plus I've added this on the windows Host:

```
127.0.0.1 themes.wp
```

If I go to

```
themes.wp
```

everything loads fine. If I try a third level domain, like

```
dummy.themes.wp
```

I get

```
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

Wordpress Network tells me this:

```
Warning! Wildcard DNS may not be configured correctly!
The installer attempted to contact a random hostname (9f3c9c.themes.wp) on your domain. 
This resulted in an error message: cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: 9f3c9c.themes.wp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, themes.wp and dummy.themes.wp different domains

Fast way: add dummy.themes.wp to you hosts file
`127.0.0.1 dummy.themes.wp`

Or install any simple dns server because `hosts` not support wildcard domains

Comment: I had to make a dozen of subdomains, I just wrote them all on the hosts and now everything works